# jquery clone select element within a <tr><td>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to clone a select and update the `name` and `id` values.  The select is within a `<tr><td>`

```
<table>
<tr id="tr_1">
    <td id="td_1">
        <select name="tech_1" id="tech_1">
            <option value="0">Please Select</option>
            <option value="1">Mango</option>
            <option value="2">Apple</option>
            <option value="3">Banana</option>
            <option value="4">Orange</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="btnClone" value="Clone" />
```

I can do it without the table, but my challenge is putting the clone within a new `<tr><td>` ... `</td></tr>`

Here is my jquery:

```
$("#btnClone").bind("click", function () {

   // get the last SELECT which ID starts with ^= "tech_"
   var $tr = $('tr[id^="tr_"]:last');

   // get the last SELECT which ID starts with ^= "tech_"
    var $select = $('select[id^="tech_"]:last');

    // Read the Number from that SELECT's ID (i.e: 3 from "tech_3")
    // And increment that number by 1
    var num = parseInt( $select.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;

    // Clone it and assign the new ID (i.e: from num 4 to ID "tech_4")
    var $klon = $select.clone().prop('id', 'tech_'+num ).prop('name', 'tech_'+num );

    // Finally insert $klon wherever you want
    $tr.after("<tr><td>").after($klon).after("</td></tr>");
});
```

This code results in the cloned `<select>` below the original  and nothing between the new `<tr><td>` and `</td></tr>`

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? It's perhaps not a problem, but it's a *long* time since I've seen `bind()` used (I'd suggest using `on()` instead, but that's perhaps my personal familiarity and preference). Incidentally do you *use* all those `id` properties? It seems you're making life difficult for yourself. Incidentally, where is your button? Somewhere outside of the `<table>`? Are you intentionally cloning the specific `<select>`, or just the *last* `<select>` element?

Comment: Any time I see selectors like `$("[id^=xxx_"])` it suggests that you should be using a class.

Comment: I've added the button code to this question.  It was in the original code.  I want to clone the last `<select>` element and the user can add as many `<select>` elements as they desire with each one having a unique id.

Answer (score 1):

Try to `append` the select element after creating the `tr` and `td`,

```
$tr.after($("<tr><td></td></tr>").find("td").append($klon).end());
```

Comment: @BrianG We have to add `.end()` to travel back in the chain. Check the answer now/

Comment: Firebug shows the <select> within <td></td> and,but not within `<tr>`.  Also, a second click on the Clone button puts the third select between the original <select> and first cloned <select>

Comment: If `true` is not added to `.clone()` children of cloned element will not be cloned

Comment: @guest271314 I heard of nothing like that. If you pass true then that will be considered as a hard clone.  So that the data present with element as well as the event bound with the element will also be copied during the cloning process.

Comment: Thanks end helped.  Also changed original `<tr>` to `<tr class="tr_tech_cont">` and modified two jquery lines: `var $tr = $('tr[class="tr_tech_cont"]:last')` and `$tr.after($("<tr class='tr_tech_cont'><td></td></tr>").find("td").append($klon).end())`

Comment: @BrianG Glad it helped you. :)

Comment: @BrianG Also the following variant of answer `$("<div>",{html:$("<span>")})` is dangerous as there is no document related to that. Its better to not to follow that approach.

Comment: _"Also the following variant of answer $("<div>",{html:$("<span>")}) is dangerous as there is no document related to that. Its better to not to follow that approach."_ ? How is approach "dangerous" ?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Also note, i was incorrect here about `.clone()` not cloning childNodes

Comment: @guest271314 There is no official document saying that it is a valid signature. That must be a glitch and it might be removed at any point. If you can quote an official doc on that then it can be considered.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy _"There is no official document saying that it is a valid signature."_ Which signature are you referencing ? Adding `html` at creation of element using `$(<element>, {html:jQuery(object)})` ?

Comment: @guest271314 `{html : htmlString}` would be the right one whereas setting jquery object to html seems weird. I am not sure why it is working. Searching for a concrete proof in document.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy You are correct, not explicitly in documentation; though see `if (elem) {
            this.empty().append(value);
        }` at http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=html . The first two `if` conditions would return `false` when jQuery object passed; then `.append()` is used internally with  `value`  as parameter

Comment: @guest271314 Very useful link. But it good to stay away from features that are not being a part in doc. As it can be removed at anytime. But I am hearing about this usage now only. Let me raise a ticket in their bugs forum.  Technically this is not a bug, but will see what they will respond. :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Actually, the approach could substitute `append:$("<div>")` for `html:$("<div>")` since `.append()` is called internally anyway; see updated post

Answer (score 1):

Add `tr` and `td` first with the `id` of `tr` and then add `select` to the `td` under new `tr` like following.

```
$("#btnClone").bind("click", function () {
    var $tr = $('tr[id^="tr_"]:last');
    var $select = $('select[id^="tech_"]:last');

    var num = parseInt($select.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10) + 1;
    var $klon = $select.clone().prop('id', 'tech_' + num).prop('name', 'tech_' + num);

    $tr.after($("<tr id=tr_" + num + "><td></td></tr>")); // change here
    $('#tr_' + num + ' td').append($klon); // change here 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create the elements rather than appending html.

```
var $klon = $select.clone().prop('id', 'tech_'+num ).prop('name', 'tech_'+num );
var newTr = $('<tr/>');
var newTd = $('<td/>');    

newTr.insertAfter($tr);        
newTr.append(newTd);
newTd.append($klon);
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/raz34m93/

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`jQuery(html, attributes)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes) <strike>; also, to include childNodes of cloned element, add `true` to `.clone(true)` , see [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone)</strike>

```
$tr.after($("<tr>", {append:$("<td>", {append:$klon})}))
```

```js
$("#btnClone").on("click", function() {

  // get the last SELECT which ID starts with ^= "tech_"
  var $tr = $('tr[id^="tr_"]:last');

  // get the last SELECT which ID starts with ^= "tech_"
  var $select = $('select[id^="tech_"]:last');

  // Read the Number from that SELECT's ID (i.e: 3 from "tech_3")
  // And increment that number by 1
  var num = parseInt($select.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10) + 1;

  // Clone it and assign the new ID (i.e: from num 4 to ID "tech_4")
  var $klon = $select.clone(true).prop('id', 'tech_' + num).prop('name', 'tech_' + num);

  // Finally insert $klon wherever you want
  $tr.after(
    $("<tr>", {
      append: $("<td>", {
        append: $klon
      })
    })
  )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="tr_1">
    <td id="td_1">
      <select name="tech_1" id="tech_1">
        <option value="0">Please Select</option>
        <option value="1">Mango</option>
        <option value="2">Apple</option>
        <option value="3">Banana</option>
        <option value="4">Orange</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="btnClone">click</button>
```

Comment: `{html:$("<td>", {html:$klon}` This will not work. As it is similar to `.html($klon)`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy _"This will not work."_ ? See stacksnippets at post

Comment: `If true is not added to .clone() children of cloned element will not be cloned` This was your statement. I understood from your statement that options inside select will not be cloned(copied) if we dont pass true. But now you are saying by quoting the doc that `user selections` and `text typed` into text area will not be copied.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I was incorrect; my initial statement is not accurate. Added note about `.clone()` and `select` elements for reference